# Why did the POSIX function strcasecmp() get such weird name?

Tags: c, posix

Does someone know the history of getting the function name [`strcasecmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcasecmp.3p.html)? Why not `stricasecmp()` - ignoring case compare? The actual name is confusing.

Might it get from **str**ing-special-**case**-**c**o**mp**are - just w/o the adjective?

Comment: It's short for "STRing CASE-insensitive CoMPare". Why would you expect the "i" before "case"?

Comment: There's no need for the "i" to specify "insensitive". `strcmp` is case-sensitive, so just putting "case" in the name implies that this is the difference.

Comment: If it were me I'd have named it "stricmp".

Comment: I would expect CASE-insensitive abbreviated with **C**ase-**I**nsensitive.

Comment: So that would be `strcicmp`

Comment: For comparison, PHP calls the case-insensensitive version of `strstr` `stristr`

Comment: Perhaps since it came around later than others, it needed a name outside the usual suspects.

Comment: IBM and Microsoft use/document `stricmp`. Arguably better. But, my guess is that this came later. By that time, `strcasecmp` was already part of the lexicon.

Comment: Strange closing reason. I would vote for opinion-based.

Comment: @273K — Agreed: I voted Opinion-Based, but the two prior close votes were different so my choice was ignored.  It means I'm reluctant to reopen because I can't help re-close.

Answer (score 3):

`strcasecmp` first appeared in 4.4BSD (or possibly 4.3 according to some sources).

From the original source code on https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/tree/master/lib/libc/string the original contributor seems to have been [Chris Torek](http://www.torek.net/torek/).

I emailed him asking for the gory details.

Comment: Looking forward to his answer.

Comment: @273K: no response so far. I'm going to try a different email address.

Comment: No response yet?

Comment: @273K: no, maybe he does not want to answer or has no interest in computing anymore, or maybe his spam filter shut me out.

Comment: Maybe ask him on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/chris-torek-85702016/?

Answer (score 1):

We talk about an environment in which the system function to create a file is named `creat`, for heaven's sake; while it is [the main error in the Unix design Ken Thompson would fix](https://archive.org/details/UNIXProgrammingEnvironment/page/204/mode/2up) if he could do it all over again, short names were the prevailing motto as witnessed by ls, cd, and, yes, strcmp. Part of that surely is rooted in the literal paper teletypes (ever wondered where /dev/tty comes from?) used for input, or in the [4 kB of RAM and a printer that prints 10 characters per second](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/03/a-brief-tour-of-the-pdp-11-the-most-influential-minicomputer-of-all-time/). If you can make your source code a few percent smaller by omitting the carriage return or having short function names, you did that.

And if there is an existing function for case sensitive comparisons named `strcmp()`, there is little doubt what `strcasecmp()` does. As standard library functions go it is very long already, for example it is longer than any in `string.h`. I bet you the author was tempted to name it `strccmp()` or at least `strcascmp()` but remembered Thompson's regret ;-).

Comment: And yet `stricmp()` sits around on a number of old systems, which easily falls much more in line with the original naming philosophy, and is, IMO, significantly less ambiguous than `strcasecmp()`.

Comment: POSIX says the functions are declared in `<strings.h>` rather than `<string.h>` and the [`strncasecmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncasecmp.html) function name is longer than `strcasecmp()` — and the `strcasecmp_l()` and `strncasecmp_l()` functions are longer still.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Huh, I missed that and was actually not aware of there being those two headers (IIUC  strcasecmp() e.a. are not part of the C standard library but of POSIX). Anyway, my main point stands.